# Dynamo GSI does not project non-key attributes that are part of the index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have the following Global Secondary index on a DynamoDb table that shows when using describe-table:

```
 "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
        {
            "IndexSizeBytes": 14339252, 
            "IndexName": "Id-AddedOn-index", 
            "Projection": {
                "ProjectionType": "INCLUDE", 
                "NonKeyAttributes": [
                    "AgentId, TicketId, TotalSecondsSinceOpen"
                ]
            },
```

However, when I execute a QueryResut using this index, the following exception is thrown:

```
 (One or more parameter values were invalid: Global secondary index Id-AddedOn-index does not project [TicketId, AgentId, TotalSecondsSinceOpen])
```

Clearly the describe table operation shows them, but a query fails to retrieve them.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I query in the AWS Table's Items tab using the index, the fields also do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

**"NonKeyAttributes"** must be given a list of strings.  Change your definition to the following and your GSI will project those attributes properly.

```
"GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
        "IndexSizeBytes": 14339252, 
        "IndexName": "Id-AddedOn-index", 
        "Projection": {
            "ProjectionType": "INCLUDE", 
            "NonKeyAttributes": [
                "AgentId", "TicketId", "TotalSecondsSinceOpen"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "ProjectionType" : "ALL" in the global secondary index

Comment: I think the question is about ProjectionType: "INCLUDE"